# Practicing constructor in Java and results is not what I expected

Tags: java, constructor

I'm learning Java and now practicing constructors..
I made my own stuff and the result of the codes is `Sales Prices: 0.0`
I don't know what I miss here.

**Code -**

```
class Sales{
    static double supply;
    static double margin=supply*0.2;
    static double vat=0.1;
    static double sale=(supply+margin)+(supply+margin)*vat;
    public Sales(double supply){
        this.supply=supply;
    }
    static void printSales(){
        System.out.println("Sales Prices: "+sale);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sales sales1 = new Sales(1000);
        sales1.printSales();
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting a static variable in a constructor seems very wrong...Very surprised none of the answers have mentioned that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calculating `sale` before you initialize `supply`, so you are working with the default value for a `double`, which is `0`. Initialize all the variables in the constructor.

```
public Sales(final double supply){
    this.supply = supply;
    this.margin=supply*0.2;
    this.vat=0.1;
    this.sale=(supply+margin)+(supply+margin)*vat;
}
```

Furthermore, all of your `static` variables apart from `vat` should be instance variables as they can be different for each instance of the class. Your `printSales` method should be an instance method as well. See the below code in action [here](https://ideone.com/KxJU0y).

```
private static final double vat = 0.1;
private final double supply;
private final double margin;
private final double sale;
public Sales(final double supply){
    this.supply = supply;
    this.margin=supply*0.2;
    this.sale=(supply+margin)+(supply+margin)*vat;
}
void printSales(){
    System.out.println("Sales Prices: "+sale);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can I put public instead private for class variables(double supply, margin, sale)? And.. do we put 'static' only for class variables? and since instance variables can be different from each instances in that case we don't put static.. did I get it right?(Sorry for my poor English ;))

Comment: @user13214669 You certainly can use `public` if you wish. Yes, instance variables should be used to store information that could be different for each instance of the class.

Comment: For last.. for the method printSales(){} I thought since it's class method I thought I need to put static..? I thought for class variable and class method we have to put static.. it's not the case..?

Comment: @user13214669 `sale` is possibly different for each instance of the class, so `printSales` should also be an instance method.

Answer (score 2):

For your program to work, you would have to initialize sale during initialization of the `sales1` object. For that, you must change your constructor as follows -

```
public Sales(double supply){
    this.supply=supply;
    this.margin=supply*0.2;
    this.sale=(supply+margin)+(supply+margin)*vat;
}
```

So, this will first initialize and assign value to `supply` and only then give value to `sale`.

In your code, you were assigning value to sale in the class itself even before you initialized or assigned value to supply. So, that's the reason it was printing 0.0 because, `sale` was not assigned a new value after `supply` was initialized in the constructor of your program.

The same holds for other variable like margin, which will also be 0, since you haven't initialized supply in your code when you have assigned value to margin. So, you are working with their default values which is 0.

**NOTE :** Only your `vat` variable is supposed to be static since it can be considered to be associated with the class. All other variables should be declared as normal variables and not static. The reason is static variables are  those that are associated with classes. You variables `supply`, `margin` and  `sale` would all different for different objects of the class and hence shouldn't be static.

---

So your final code should look like this -

```
class Sales{    
    private double supply;
    private double margin;
    private double sale;
    private static final double vat = 0.1;    
    public Sales(double supply){
        this.supply = supply;
        this.margin=supply*0.2;
        this.sale=(supply+margin)+(supply+margin)*vat;
    }
    void printSales(){
        System.out.println("Sales Prices: "+sale);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sales sales1 = new Sales(1000);
        sales1.printSales();
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Sales Prices: 1320.0
```

Hope this clears the doubt !